# Java Key Store and HTTPS for server to server communication not working

Tags: https, logstash, logstash-configuration, jks

This is my first time working with Java Key Store and I am having a bit of difficulty. I have `ServerA` sending logs to `ServerB`. I am able to establish an unsecure `http` communication that traffics the logs. However, when incorporating `JKS` to establish a secure communication using `https` nothing seems to be received by `ServerB`. How can two servers communicate securely using `JKS`?

Below is how I am currently setting all of this up:

Creating a keystore in `ServerA`:

In `ServerA` generate Self-Signed Certificate in Keystore

```
keytool -genkey \
        -alias jkstest \
        -keyalg RSA \
        -validity 365 \
        -keystore /apps/logstash/jkstest.jks
        -keysize 2048
```

In `ServerA` extract certificate

```
keytool -export \
        -rfc -alias jkstest \
        -keystore /apps/logstash/jkstest.jks \
        -file /apps/logstash/jkstest.crt 
        -storepass somepass
```

From `ServerA` copy key store to `ServerB`

```
scp /apps/logstash/jkstest.jks username@serverb.com:/apps/logstash/jkstest.jks
```

I am using [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.2/index.html) to send logs from `ServerA` to `ServerB`. It is a pretty straight forward application to download and install. The crucial/imporant part is in the configuration where the JKS is used:

`ServerA` config.conf

```
input {
        file {
                path => "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
                start_position => beginning
        }
}
output {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
        http {
                http_method => "post"
                codec => "json_lines"
                url => "https://serverb.com:5000/"
                ssl_certificate_validation => true
                cacert => "/apps/logstash/jkstest.crt"
        }
}
```

`ServerB` config.conf

```
input {
  http {
        port => 5000
        codec => json
        ssl => true
        keystore => "/apps/logstash/jkstest.jks"
        keystore_password => "hardt0gu355"
  }
}
output {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
}
```

To start sending and receiving logs:

`ServerA` start logstash

```
bin/logstash agent -f config.conf -l logstash.log
```

`ServerB` start logstash

```
bin/logstash agent -f config.conf -l logstash.log
```

Comment: try with `ssl_certificate_validation => false` since it's a self-signed certificate it probably can't be fully validated.

Comment: It's been a long time since I did one of these, but since you are using a self-signed cert, you wont be able to import it as a 'trusted cert-chain', and chaining it to one of the pre-packaged trusted cert authorities .  So, for the other server to trust, it probably has to be manually imported as a trusted cert on both ends?

Comment: @djangofan I am not sure if I did something similar to that but still nothing gets received in the other server. Can you test on your end to see if the  way you did it still works?

Comment: Maybe this provides another hint.  I cant really add more to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227849/client-server-ssl-communication-self-signed-certificate

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but, on server A you should [configure a truststore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-truststore) with your generated certificate as trusted certificate.

Not a cacert (unless you also have certificate authority certitificate, but yours seems self signed )

Comment: Good point. I created a `truststore` on `serverA`. Using the certificate that i created in `SeverB` from its own `keystore`. However, no luck. Ran this on `serverA` to create trustore `keytool -importcert -file serverB.cer  -alias mycert -keystore truststore.jks`. Are you able to replicate or get it to communicate over  ssl?

Comment: I had it working with beats ( e.g. FileBeat ) to LogStash with following https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.0/configuring-ssl-logstash.html

Comment: Filebeat is the preferred solution. However, I am trying to get this to work from logstash to logstash instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two approaches in you case:

Then you have ssl_certificate_validation=true  you should provide truststore in both sides - ServerA and ServerB. 
In your setup you provide only cacert on ServerA and keystore on ServerB.
But you should to have a keystore and trustore defined on both servers.

So you can do the following thing

1) Use same keystore on both servers and use same truststore on both servers too. This very insecure approach.

2) You have to generate independent server and client keystore and then exchange their public key (certs) see example http://ruchirawageesha.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-create-clientserver-keystores.html in this case you can use *cacert* instead of truststore.

or you can generate independent CA and generate signed certificates(https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/introduction.html). 
This is much better approach, but maybe it will a little overhead in your case.

Comment: I followed the 2nd option but still didnt work. The [output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.2/plugins-outputs-http.html) has two flags `keystore` and `truststore`. I tested with both and nothing.